# Haskell - make a 2D list out of a 1D list

Tags: haskell

I have to make a 2D list `[[Int]]`. out of a 1D list `[Int]` in Haskell.

The function should take to args "r" Int indicates the count of rows and a 1D list, which should be sliced into rows with the length of "r".

If length of the list is longer than r*r then the rest of the list should be dropped.
Howerver
If length of the list is shorter than r*r then the missing elements should be inserted in the list as 0.

**Example 1:**

Input:
r = 2

list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Output: [[1,2], [3,4]]

**Example 2:**

Input:
r = 3

list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Output: [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [0,0,0]]

So my approach is over thre functions as follow:

```
zeroList :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
zeroList r myList = (take (r*r-(length myList)) (0 : zeroList r myList))

processList  ::  Int  ->  [Int]  ->  [[Int]]
processList  r myList = (if (length myList < r*r)
                        then (myList:(zeroList r myList))
                        else if (length (myList > r*r))
                        then (reverse (drop r (reverse myList)))
                        else 
                                myList)

make2DList  ::  Int  ->  [Int]  ->  [[Int]]                     


make2DList r myList = (if myList == [] 
                        then make2DList
                    else ( ( take r (processList r myList) ):( make2DList r ( drop r (processList r myList) ) )))
```

The zeroList function works properly but the other two functions don't work. I some compiling error messages:

```
D:\haskell\task1.hs:6:63:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `Int'
    Expected type: [[Int]]
      Actual type: [Int]
    In the return type of a call of `zeroList'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `(zeroList r myList)'

D:\haskell\task1.hs:14:54:
    Couldn't match expected type `[[Int]]'
                with actual type `Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]'
    In the expression: make2DList
    In the expression:
      (if myList == [] then
           make2DList
       else
           ((take r myList) : (make2DList r (drop r myList))))
    In an equation for `make2DList':
        make2DList r myList
          = (if myList == [] then
                 make2DList
             else
                 ((take r myList) : (make2DList r (drop r myList))))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

I can't comprehend, why it doesn't work although `zeroList r myList`. returns an ordinary list.

Could anyone help me please?

Answer (score 6):

I have to admit that I don’t comprehend how you are trying to do it. All this `if then else` is quite unHaskellish. :-) Also, due to Haskell’s lazy evaluation and infinite lists, it is unnecessary to compute the exact number of needed zeroes etc. beforehand.

A rough draft how it could be done instead:

```
make2DList r l = take r . chunks r $ l ++ zeroes
  where
    zeroes = [0,0..]
    chunks r xs = take r xs : chunks r (drop r xs)
```

Explanation:

1. Extend the list by an infinite number of zeroes so we don’t have to worry about padding anymore.
2. Make a `chunks` function that splits any list into chunks of the given length.
3. Apply `chunks` to the padded list.
4. Take as many rows as we need.

Comment: where `chunks r $ l ++ zeroes` == `chunks r (l ++ zeroes)` — possibly easier to read for a n00b

Comment: thanks for the nice and compact code and for the explaination. It works just fine - however I can't comprehend it right away :-( 1. In wicht library is chunks? Becaus when I write chunks in the Prelude, it says `<interactive>:1:1: Not in scope: `chunks'`. 2. Is it written in free-point style (1. line?) how can one write it in the "normal" (btw, what is it called?) style? 3. what do $ and `zeroes = [0,0..]`. do?

Comment: @Beetle 952580, thanks. Yes indeed it is easier for me and probably for every newbie. The point-free ist a little bit tricky for beginners

Comment: Actually, it isn’t really point-free – that would mean to get rid of the `r l` altogether. (Not easily possible here).

Comment: `chunks` is no standard function. I defined it myself (the last code line is the definition).

Comment: Oh, and `zeroes` is just an infinite list of zeroes, also defined here (line 3). You can replace it with `[0,0..]` if you prefer. (Alternatively, you could define it as `zeroes = 0 : zeroes`.)

Comment: chirlu: You could define zeroes as `zeroes = repeat 0`

Comment: @Beetle 952580 I don't have the edit option for that comment anymore. I'll take care about it next time. Thanks for link about where - now I understand where. I didn't use `where`. in ghci but I tried to use `chunks`. there since I was unaware of it, that it wasn't a Haskel-function..

Comment: @chirlu thanks for your help, now it's more clear, however I don't understand yet how the $ function works. Is it possible to rewrite it without $ or does it get complicated?

Comment: I've made a mistake. `take r . chunks r $ l ++ zeroes` should actually be `(take r . chunks r) (l ++ zeroes)` without the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

I can explain both of the compilation errors, and I have a question for you. I'll take the errors in reverse order.

## Error at 14:54

First I'll explain how arguments are applied to functions in Haskell.

The function `make2DList` has type `Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]`, which is equivalent to `Int -> ( [Int] -> [[Int]] )`. This means that, if given one argument `r` (which must be of type `Int`) it returns a function of type `[Int] -> [[Int]]`. This returned function, if given an argument `myList` (which must be of type `[Int]`) returns a list of type `[[Int]]`.

This means that the code `make2DList r myList` is equivalent to `(make2DList r) myList`. In any case, it must return a value of type `[[Int]]`, that is, a list of lists of `Int`s.

But you have said that, in the event that `myList` is empty, it should return just `make2DList`. Unfortunately `make2DList` is a function of type `Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]` and not a list of lists of type `[[Int]]`, hence the compiler error message

```
    Couldn't match expected type `[[Int]]'
                with actual type `Int -> [Int] -> [[Int]]'
```

The fix is to supply some arguments to this call to `make2DList`. But do not supply an empty list as the second argument, or you will create an infinite loop. Probably what you actually want to do is to return an empty list of lists, written the same way as an empty list of anything: `[]`

**Edit:** I should perhaps also explain how `if` ... `then` ... `else` works in Haskell. This is not at all like the if/then/else in imperative languages, and is actually just like the [ternary operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Conditional-Expressions). That is,

```
if a then b else c
```

in Haskell is, as far as I can tell, exactly the same as

```
a ? b : c
```

in another language.

Thus, in order for the whole expression `(if a then b else c)` to be of the right type, both `b` and `c` must be of the right type (and `a` must be boolean, of course). In your case, the whole if/then/else expression should be of type `[[Int]]` but your `b` is the expression `make2DList` (with no arguments), which is of course a function and not a list of lists as it should be.

## Error at 6:63

The type of `:` is given by `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. This means that if whatever is on the left of the `:` has type `a` (for some *a*), then whatever is on the right should have type `[a]`.

That is to say, whatever appears to the left of `:` will become the first element in the resulting list, and whatever is on the right of `:` will become *the rest of the list*, which means that the type of the rest of the list must be a list of the type of whatever the first element is.

Your first element is `myList`, which has type `[Int]`, and what you're trying to use for the rest of the list is `(zeroList r myList)`, which also has type `[Int]` and is thus only good as a single element.

Possible fixes (which would compile, but may or may not be correct) could include:

- enclosing `zeroList r myList` in square brackets, thus:

  ```
  myList:[zeroList r myList]
  ```

  which would always create a list of two elements, each of which would be a list of `Int`s
- concatenating the two lists, thus:

  ```
  myList ++ (zeroList r myList)
  ```

  but this would produce the wrong return type, so you'd have to put the result in another list. The following would compile, but is almost certainly not what you want:

  ```
  [myList ++ (zeroList r myList)]
  ```

That `r` probably wants to be something like `r - (length myList)` or something too.

## Question

I'm having trouble guessing how your functions are supposed to work. What are each of the two functions `processList` and `make2DList` supposed to do? I see that they both have the same type, so what is the difference?

Comment: My intention was to creat make2DList as the "super" function, which should return the final result. Within it it should call the processList function which should check the length of myList and depending of whether myList is shorter or longer than r*r it should concatinate some zeros (for this step it shoul call zeroList) or drop the overflow of elements.

Comment: I see that I had forgotten to call `processList`. within make2DList. Now I updated it s. above! Anyhow it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

```
import Data.List (replicate)

takeElse :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
takeElse 0 _   _        = []
takeElse n alt []       = replicate n alt
takeElse n alt (x : xs) = x : takeElse (n - 1) alt xs

exotic :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [[a]]
exotic dum alt lst = exot dim lst
   where
      exot 0 _  = []
      exot n xs = takeElse dim alt xs : exot (n - 1) (drop dim xs)
```

such that

```
exotic 3 0 [1,2,3,4]  ==  [[1,2,3],[4,0,0],[0,0,0]]
exotic 1 ' ' "Hello"  ==  ["H"]
exotic 4 ' ' "Hello"  ==  ["Hell","o   ","    ","    "]

takeElse 10 ' ' "Hello"  ==  "Hello     "
```